# HP ProLiant DL320e G8 v2 - USB2.0 during POST

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, usb

Initially my USB2.0 ports were working during POST (and boot). However, now they appear not to be. I first noticed this when I could not access the RBSU by pressing F9 during POST. Then found that I couldn't boot from USB either (I was able to do both of these initially). When performing the boot via iLo remote console I can access all of the setups (i.e., all of the F(X)'s) and can boot virtual media from a 'removable drive'. Keyboard works fine once the OS is booted.

Not really sure what to try here.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Nick.

Comment: Have you done a full power off of the system including removing power-cord for 10 seconds? if that doesn't work you may have a faulty part on the system board.

Comment: I have done a full power off.

Comment: [**(people should stop buying DL3XXe servers!!)**](http://serverfault.com/questions/562574/install-oracle-linux-6-4-on-hp-proliant-dl380e-gen8-server/562576#562576)

Comment: Could this be a ROM issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you give us more information on what you're trying to do?

- On your keyboard, does the caps-lock key work?
- Are you using a KVM switch at all, because *[weird things can happen](https://serverfault.com/questions/465883/hp-proliant-dl360-g7-hangs-at-power-and-thermal-calibration-screen)*?

Also see: [Is there a better workaround or solution to boot a Proliant DL380 Gen8 from USB DVD drive than "Restore Default System Settings"?](https://serverfault.com/questions/556775/is-there-a-better-workaround-or-solution-to-boot-a-proliant-dl380-gen8-from-usb/558021#558021)

Please use your ILO to check the RBSU and navigate to the USB port settings in the BIOS.

- Make sure the external ports are not disabled.
- Check your drive boot ordering settings.
- Upgrade your system firmware through [Intelligent Provisioning (`F10`)](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5219984#!tab=features).
- If all else fails, reset the BIOS settings to default.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Restart. USB keyboard attached to server (KB1). USB keyboard for remote console (KB2). During POST, KB1 not working (caps-lock not producing caps light). KB2 working. RBSU settings look good (no changes made). Restart. KB1 now working during POST. Server to halt. Hookup monitor & kill remote console session (iLo cable removed). Restart. KB1 no longer working :(

Comment: Halt. Reconnect iLo & swap monitors. Start. KB1 not working. KB2 works - going to Intelligent Provisioning. Will return with results.

Comment: Everything up-to-date - nothing installed. Reboot.

Comment: KB1 works during POST. Boot OS and then halt. Start up again. KB1 no longer working during POST. Appears that whenever I use KB2 during POST, KB1 will work during POST the next start - but not after that... Do I want to 'System Default Options -> Restore Default System Settings'?

Comment: While in RBSU plugs KB1 into another USB2.0 slot - doesn't work. Plugs into USB3.0 slot - works... Sorry! Not true, front USB2.0 ports didn't work. But back did.

Comment: Back USB2.0 ports continue to work during POST (after a few more restarts). While I'm ready to just accept this, do you have any theories?

Comment: @user3513346 Yes. See: http://serverfault.com/q/556775/13325