# Resetting factory defaults - HP Proliant DL360 gen8

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, usb, bios

I have an HP Proliant DL360 gen8 server that seems to have USB turned off in the BIOS. I would like to enable it again.

With the USB turned off, I cannot intervene during POST - the USB keyboard does not work. I have tried to use the virtual keyboard through the ILO 4 Remote Control access and it appears that it uses USB emulation...so this does not work either.

The server also has no CD drive.

I have tried:
1) Resetting switch 6 ON/OFF but this does not clear the bios.
2) Removing the battery, again to no avail.
3) Connecting to ILO ssh server and sending a 'reset hard' command...no change.

Does anyone know how I can get reset to factory defaults? (either with switches, jumpers or another command I can send through the ILO ssh server)

btw: The 'reset hard' command seems to only reset ILO, not the server configuration, nor the BIOS.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard or USB port (front versus rear)?

Comment: When removing the battery make sure the machine PSU isn't connected, otherwise the CMOS gets its power from the +5VSB line from the PSU and stays powered even without the battery. Also press the power button a couple times once the battery is removed to discharge any residual current in capacitors.

Comment: After a lengthy remote debugging process with an HP technician, we concluded the board is faulty and it will be replaced (it is still under warranty). For those who have found themselves having disabled the USB port and now trying to access, there is a thread which describes a solution: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/DL160-G6-How-to-enable-USB-remotely/m-p/6371451/highlight/true#M140830

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know how the USB controller ended up disabled on your system... I'd love to know what happened right before you asked this question...

But you do have a couple of options to recover. Since there's no PS/2 port on this line of servers, I guess keyboard input doesn't work. Is there an OS loaded already? Are you [suuuure that your keyboard/KVM switch is known-good](https://serverfault.com/questions/465883/hp-proliant-dl360-g7-hangs-at-power-and-thermal-calibration-screen)?

Try the battery again. The [ProLiant DL360p Gen8 Server Maintenance and Service Guide](http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c03242811-8.pdf) says that the battery is the right way to restore system defaults.

[image]

---

You can also reset the system settings using the proper jumper sequence.

- Remove all power supplies from the chassis
- Locate the System Maintenance Switch on the motherboard - It's a set of 10 DIP switches.
- Turn switch #6 switch on.
- Insert all power supply units.
- Power on the server and allow it to idle for 3 minutes.
- Power the server off.
- Remove all power supplies.
- Return DIP switch #6 to off (original) position.
- Reinsert the power supplies.
- Power the server on.

Also see:

[Is there a better workaround or solution to boot a Proliant DL380 Gen8 from USB DVD drive than "Restore Default System Settings"?](https://serverfault.com/questions/556775/is-there-a-better-workaround-or-solution-to-boot-a-proliant-dl380-gen8-from-usb)

and

[HP Proliant Gen8 boot failure after bios upgrade and processor upgrade](https://serverfault.com/questions/609338/hp-proliant-gen8-boot-failure-after-bios-upgrade-and-processor-upgrade/609344#609344)

Comment: This is definitely the solution if there are no hardware problems, should I mark it as accepted?

Comment: @eskimoroll Sure!!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Your External USB keys were set to disable, its very simple to fix: remove the cover from your DL360PG8, plug your USB keyboard into the single USB port located "on the motherboard" in front of the power supplies, power up server & wait for F9 BIOS setting to come up at the end of post, here you will be able to get into the F9 settings command from your keyboard, at the 1st drop down menu in the F9 menu click "SYSTEM OPTIONS", scroll down 3 lines to "USB Options" & click, 1st option in the box will be "USB Control" & click on it, a gray box will open with 2 options, click on "USB Enable", after hit "Escape key" 3 times to exit and you will be all set. Good Luck!